# Что именно отправит this?

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такая кнопка,что именно отправит this в  функцию delRowTes?

```
tddelbutpoletest.innerHTML='<BUTTON type="button" id="del'+k+n+'"Value="' 
 + n +'" style="height:25px; font-size:10px; line-height:1;"  onClick="delRowTes(this)"
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PL8SG/

Answer (score 6):

`this` в обработчике - это элемент, по которому кликнули:

```js
function myFunc(th) {
  console.log(th);
}
```

```html
<input type='button' value='text' onclick='myFunc(this);' />
```

Answer (score 0):

в `delRowTes(element)` отправит элемент `button` который имеет `id="del'+k+n+'"`